# Finding the number of divs with a certain id in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a way to count the number of divs with the id "blue". Is this possible in BeautifulSoup? Here is my code:

```
import BeautifulSoup

scanning = True

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("<html><body><div id='blue'></div><div id='blue'></div><div id='purple'></div></body></html>")

blues = []

blues.append(soup.find("div", {"id": "blue"}))

print len(blues)
```

Answer (score 1):

the find method will only fetch the first occurence, hence the output of 1. If you use find_all, it will literally find all of the occurences, saving the results to a list on your behalf. In this case 'divs' becomes a list of every div id=blue, and you can check the length of that.

```
import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup("<html><body><div id='blue'></div><div id='blue'></div><div id='purple'></div></body></html>", 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "blue"})

print(len(divs))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `div`s only have the `id` blue, then you could just use:

```
divs = soup.find_all("#blue")
blues = len(divs) if divs else 0
```